# Is it possible to have more than one value in a single subscript in a BASH array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I am creating a script that will process Cisco serial numbers and produce their manufacturing date.

I am using the following array to handle the Month portion and that works with no issue. That array is setup as so:

```
declare -A d_year

d_year[10]="2006"
d_year[11]="2007"
d_year[12]="2008"
d_year[13]="2009"
d_year[14]="2010"
d_year[15]="2011"
```

The issue comes from the Month portion since numbers 1 ~ 5 = January, 6 ~ 9 = February. I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
declare -A d_month

d_month[{1:5}]="January"
d_month[{6..9}]="February"
d_month[{10..14}]="March"
```

When it attempts to process the serial number, the year portion comes out with no issues but the month produces the following error(it produces error for the other ill formatted sections of the array):

```
 syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{15..18}")
```

I can do it line by line but feel that there is an easier way that I may be missing? So my question is, is it possible to create an array in this way to process a range of numbers?

Comment: So you want to assign 1 value to multiple array indices at once?

Comment: I believe so, so like how my month array looks like, if I can put 1 ~ 5 into one value so that it produces January, that is the conclusion I am trying to get to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you please try:

```
for m in {1..5}; do d_month[$m]="January"; done
for m in {6..10}; do d_month[$m]="February"; done
for m in {11..15}; do d_month[$m]="March"; done
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much! It never occured to me about combing a "FOR" operation with the array!

Comment: @kuroikenshi thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works. And your comment encourages me. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO `case` is the right choice for that, could you try this

```
#!/bin/bash

d_year=$1
d_month=$2

case $d_year in
    10) year="2006";;
    11) year="2007";;
    12) year="2008";;
    13) year="2009";;
    14) year="2010";;
    15) year="2011";;
esac

case $d_month in
    [1-5]) month="January" ;;
    [6-9]) month="February";;
   1[0-4]) month="March"   ;;
esac

echo $month $year
```

Usage

```
$ ./test 12 14
March 2008
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a small script that shows you how to achieve this using a custom function:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A d_month;

function put() {
    for i in $(seq $1 $2); do 
        d_month[$i]="$3";
    done;
}

put 1 5 "January";
put 6 9 "February";
put 10 14 "March";


for i in "${!d_month[@]}"; do
    echo "$i => ${d_month[$i]}";
done;
```

The `for` loop at the bottom is just to show the contents of the array, and is not part of the functionality of the funtion.

Answer (score 0):

Integer based arrays can be defined in several ways. A less common way is the use of

```
a=( [20]="value" [30]="value" )
```

which creates an integer-based array with 2 elements with index 20 and 30.

This can now be exploited using `printf` and `eval`:

```
d_year=( [10]=2006 [11]=2007 [12]=2008 [13]=2009 [14]=2010 [15]=2011 )
d_month=()
eval d_month+=( $(printf '[%d]="January" '  {1..5}  ) )
eval d_month+=( $(printf '[%d]="February" ' {6..9}  ) )
eval d_month+=( $(printf '[%d]="March" '    {10..14}) )
```